Distribution of collisions in gas explained in Feynman lectures
I am referring to this part of Feynman lectures "39–5 The ideal gas law" (https://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/I_39.html#Ch39-F2) where he shows that the Ideal gas law also works for diatomic molecules by showing the mean kinetic energy of the center of a mass of the molecule is calculated the same way.
$$
\left\langle \frac{1}{2} M v_{\text{CM}}^2 \right\rangle = \frac{3}{2} k T \\
$$
With the internal velocities $v_A$ and $v_B$ of the molecule it can be shown that
$$
\left\langle \frac{1}{2} M v_{\text{CM}}^2 \right\rangle = \frac{3}{2} k T + \frac{m_A m_B \left\langle \textbf{v}_A \cdot \textbf{v}_B \right\rangle}{M}.
$$
The dotproduct of the two velocities needs to be zero on average, which implies that there is no preferred direction. Feynman proofs that by
\begin{align}
\left\langle (\textbf{v}_A-\textbf{v}_B)\cdot \textbf{v}_{CM} \right\rangle = 0. 
\end{align}
$\textbf{v}_A-\textbf{v}_B$ is called the relative velocity. Why is it trivial that the relative velocity does not have a preferred direction, which with some calculations shows that the internal velocities $v_A$ and $v_B$ dont have either.

"I hope this screenshot isn't too long." Rather, you should be typing out the relevant section of text, using Mathjax as necessary. Images are not accessible to everyone

You can also link to the online and freely available version of the lectures.

Also, you should really spend more effort writing down what your problem actually is. Because everything that is there is intuitive; the centre of mass velocity is intuitive, the relative velocity is intuitive, the relations are intuitive, so what is it you are hoping to get clarification on?

@BioPhysicist Sorry Im not familiar with Mathajx but Ive seen that some basic latex commands work. Any tips to improve the thread even more?

this question looks very similar, asking about almost the same equation, but is talking about two atoms colliding in an ideal gas as opposed to a single diatomic molecule with two atoms

Imagine that the relative velocity between the two atoms in a diatomic molecule had a preferred direction. Then $v_A-v_B\neq 0$ on average. You would then expect the atoms to be moving at different speeds on average, so after a while one atom would be much farther away from the other atom than where they started. This would not be a diatomic molecule anymore, it would be two atoms drifting apart!
The point is that something must be binding the two atoms together for them to form a diatomic molecule. Their relative velocities have to be constrained so that they "stay together as a pair" on average. Sure, they can move relative to each other at any instant in time, but on average they should not be drifting apart or moving closer together or else they won't comprise a stable molecule.
